# Get a number from tablecell as a number with decimals

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to move numbers in table around and have it make some calculations. The number var asrev is pulling has a $ sign right before it, and all numbers in table have decimals. Here is how I was trying to make it work.

```
           //AS Rev
           var elementsasrev = $(this).parent().find('tr').filter('.'+trclass);
           var asrev = parseInt(elementsasrev.eq(1).find("td:nth-child(6)").html());
           if(typeof asrev !== "undefined") {
            $('.'+trclass).not(this).find(".asrev").html(asrev);
           }               
           //FBspend
           var fbspend = parseInt($(this).find("td:nth-child(7)").html() );
           $(this).find(".fbspend").html(fbspend);
           //Profit
           var profit= asrev - fbspend;
           $(this).find(".profit").html(profit).css('color','#479e3a');
```

In the end, it gets fbspend as a whole number with no decimals, and for asrev and profit I get NaN

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `parseFloat()` instead of `parseInt()`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat

Comment: changed. Still the same thing

Answer (score 0):

Don't know your HTML structure, but if you have $ sign before numbers, you should do something like this:

```js
  var asrev = parseFloat($('tr').eq(0).find("td:nth-child(1)").html());
           var data = $('tr').eq(0).find("td:nth-child(1)").html();
          console.log(asrev);
          console.log(parseFloat(data.replace('$',''))); // this is what you need
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="data">

  <tr>
    <td>$66.66</td>
    <td>Entry First Line 2</td>
    <td>Entry First Line 3</td>
    <td>Entry First Line 4</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

So, first remove $ sign, which will not produce desired result, either you use parseInt or or parseFloat, and get value you need.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use parseFloat, but first remove the $ from the string.

```
var asrev = parseFloat(elementsasrev.eq(1).find("td:nth-child(6)").html().replace('$','');
...
var fbspend = parseFloat($(this).find("td:nth-child(7)").html() );
...
var profit = asrev - fbspend;
```

You're getting the NaN because `asrev` is not a number - it contains the "$" sign; you're trying to perform math on a string and an integer and get a float - that's not going to work.

Comment: It looks like you forgot the closing bracket at the end of first line. Though, when i added it, console underlined this part as error .replace('$','') );